# Chart.js 4.0.1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined

Tags: ajax, chart.js, referenceerror

I wrote an AJAX Javascript code for my ESP32 datalogger which worked so far using old versions of Chart.js. The website hosted by the ESP32 is not working anylonger if I use a more recent of Chart.js.
The error message I caught is:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined at datalogin.html

The line in the code involved is this one

```
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

Something in the interpretation seems to occur at a very early stage. But I could not identify what. See code below.

I already tried different Chart.js repository in order to have it working. It had absolutly no influence. I actively looked using different browser regarding this specific problematic and I could not find any way of solving this problem.

Thanks a lot for your support

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>EFM Meter loggin interface</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="lightning.ico">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/blob/master/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.0.1/chart.js" ></script>
  <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns@2.0.1/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.js"></script>
  <style>
  .jumbotron {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Elektrofeldmeter Data Logging Page</h1>
  </div>


  <div class="container">
<div class="border border-2 m-2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 ">
        <div class="container-sm">
          <canvas id="myChart" style="" height="152"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="border border-2 m-2">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h3> Parameters setup</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="border border-2 m-2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label for="customRange1" class="form-label" id="labelPWM">PWM of motor: 190</label>
        <input type="range" class="form-range"  min="0" max="190"  step="1" value="190" onchange="rangeValue(this)" id="customRange1">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="customRange2" class="form-label" id="labelYmin">Y min: -5000</label>
        <input type="range" class="form-range"  min="-5000" max="5000"  step="1" value="-5000" onchange="rangeY()" id="Ymin">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="customRange2" class="form-label" id="labelYmax">Y max: +5000 0</label>
        <input type="range" class="form-range"  min="-5000" max="5000"  step="1" value="5000" onchange="rangeY()" id="Ymax">
      </div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="saveAs()">*.CSV</button>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <script>

function rangeValue(element) {
  console.log(element.value);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "/pwm?value="+element.value, true);
  xhr.send();
  document.getElementById("labelPWM").innerHTML = "PWM of motor: " + element.value;
};

function rangeY() {
  myChart.options.scales.y.max = document.getElementById('Ymax').value;
  myChart.options.scales.y.min = document.getElementById('Ymin').value;
  myChart.update();
};

function clkOrientation(element) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "/clk?value="+element.checked, true);
  xhr.send();
}

  const animation = { };

  const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      datasets: [{
        borderColor: '#fc9905',
        borderWidth: 2,
        radius: 0,
        data: 0
      }
    ]
    },
    options: {
      animation,
      interaction: {
        intersect: false
      },
      plugins: {
        legend: false
      },
      scales: {
        x: {
          type: 'time',
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'time',
            color: '#000000',
             font: {
                        size: 20
                    }
          },
          ticks :
          {
            color: '#000000',
            font: {
                       size: 12
                   }
          }
        },
        y: {
          type: 'linear',
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Electrical field [V/m] @ PWM=190',
            color: '#000000',
             font: {
                        size: 20
                    }
          },
          ticks :
          {
            color: '#000000',
            font: {
                       size: 12
                   }
          }
        }
      },
      plugins: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Electrical field value [V/m]'
            }
        }
    }
  };

  Chart.defaults.font.size = 20;
  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  const myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);


function addData(chart, data) {
    for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++){
            chart.data.datasets[0].data.push({"x":data[i].x,"y":(data[i].y-32.671)/0.48025});
          };
    chart.update();
};

function getData() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  var txt = this.responseText;
  var array = JSON.parse(txt); //Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

  addData(myChart,array);
    }
  };

  xhttp.open("GET", "readEFM", true); //Handle readADC server on ESP32
  xhttp.send();
};


setInterval(function() {
getData();
}, 5000);



txt = '[{"x":1662921606250,"y":35.71},{"x":1662921606450,"y":35.61},{"x":1662921606650,"y":35.70},{"x":1662921606850,"y":35.74},{"x":1662921607050,"y":35.78},{"x":1662921607250,"y":35.45},{"x":1662921607450,"y":35.65},{"x":1662921607650,"y":35.66},{"x":1662921607850,"y":35.78},{"x":1662921608050,"y":35.76}]';
const myArr = JSON.parse(txt);
addData(myChart,myArr);
myChart.update();


function saveAs(){
  let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
  for (var i = 0 ; i < myChart.data.datasets[0].data.length; i++){
  csvContent+=myChart.data.datasets[0].data[i].x + "," + myChart.data.datasets[0].data[i].y + "\n";
  }
  var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
  link.setAttribute("download", "EFM_log.csv");
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the issue is the CHART.JS is not loasde. The URL to get CHART.JS is referring to GITHUB page which is not a JS but an HTML page, AFA I have seen.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. I retried all the JS references available on https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js this link drove me to at least 5 different js script. I changed the src link in my webpage without any effect at all.

Comment: Can you try the following: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.0.1/dist/chart.umd.min.js?

Comment: Hi, yes I tried this. Aslo not working with the same error message.

Comment: The issue is related to "type=module" of script HTML tag. See here the codepen where sounds working (your code): https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/mdKvKXj